Why/when/where was `mydict[*mylist]` introduced?
This shorthand to use lists as dict keys works in Python 3.12:
mydict = {(1, 2, 3): 'works!'}
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
print(mydict[*mylist])

In 3.10 it gives SyntaxError and in 3.11 it works (at least in the versions I tried). I searched What’s New In Python 3.11 but didn't see anything about it. Maybe it was a side effect of some other change. Why/where/when was it introduced? Looking for (information from) a GitHub issue / pull request or so.

This seems to be related.

This issue has been closed as a duplicate of a proposal related to the typing module. So I think that this feature is a byproduct, and that this is the reason why it is not documented. Funny thing is, "What's New In Python 3.11" states "Starred unpacking expressions can now be used in for statements.", but it seems that this has been available since 3.9. So it's not even the first time.
